# Github application using angular 4

Tags: angular

I have written a code to fetch the details of github users using their github username .
Here is my code

profile.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileService } from '../profile.service';

@Component({
selector: 'gg-profile',
templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
  export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  profile:any[];
  repos: any[];
  username:string;

 constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) { 

 }

findProfile(){
this.profileService.updateProfile(this.username);
this.profileService.getProfileInfo().subscribe(profile => {
    console.log(profile);
    this.profile = profile;
});

   this.profileService.getProfileRepos().subscribe(repos => {
    console.log(repos);
    this.repos = repos;
   })   
  }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 }
```

Here, If i am typing the username in input field , simultaneously i am getting the user details . But i want that there should be submit button below that input field . when i enter the username in input field and click in submit button , then it should redirect me to some other page and in that page it display the details of users . So what all need to add in my code in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `profile component.ts` :

add this to your contructor :

`private fb: FormBuilder`

add a variable like this: `public formGroup: FormGroup;`

in your `onInit` function add this :

```
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
  username: ''
});
```

in your `profile.component.html` file edit the form tag in this way :

```
<form action="" class="search-form" [formGroup]="formGroup">
```

edit your edit text for username in this way :

edit the a link in this way : 
View profile on github

in your `profile.component.ts` add a basic class :

```
class User{
  public username: string;
}
```

in your `profile.component.ts` edit the `findProfile` function

```
findProfile(){
const username = this.formGroup.value as User;
this.profileService.updateProfile(username);
this.profileService.getProfileInfo().subscribe(profile => {
    console.log(profile);
    this.profile = profile;
});

   this.profileService.getProfileRepos().subscribe(repos => {
    console.log(repos);
    this.repos = repos;
   })   
  }
```

I have no idea when you want to redirect your user, anyway the right way is to user `Router`, so this is an example on how to do it:

Add this to your constructor:

`private router: Router`

create a function `redirectUser()` like this :

```
public redirectUser(): void {
  if(true){
    this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
  }
}
```

**Note: /profile is just an example path**

I guess the code `this.profileService.updateProfile(username);` just save the username somehow / somewhere. If you want to display the user's data into the `profile` page, simply get it back and show them inside a common html file.

Answer (score 0):

You have called your function on keyup, it will behave as that.

**Remove : ** `(keyup)="findProfile()"`

create a submit type button and define a submit method that will take user's input value i.e, `<button type="submit" (click)= "submit()">`,

now in this submit method receive the input value from ngModel and the pass this value to your`findProfile()` method.

**THIS will bring you data for user details when you click the submit button**

Now in your `findProfile` method, when you receive a success response, redirect to your new url, i.e,:

```
findProfile(){
this.profileService.updateProfile(this.username);
this.profileService.getProfileInfo().subscribe(profile => {
console.log(profile);
this.profile = profile;
window.open("your/new/url", "_blank");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you have wriiten "now in this submit method receive the input value from ngModel and the pass this value to yourfindProfile() method ". Can you explain me in code, how to do that.

Comment: `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search git users 
   with username" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" click=findProfile()>`, this is what you have used, Now in findProfile: bring the input value as you were doing before or else use a formGroup